# Return reversed integer - Java

Tags: java, integer

The question is from [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/127/strings/880/).

Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer.

```
Example 1:

Input: 123
Output: 321

Example 2:

Input: -123
Output: -321

Example 3:

Input: 120
Output: 21
```

> Note: Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2^31,  2^31 − 1]. For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows.

---

**My solution**:

```
class Solution {
    public int reverseInteger(int num) {

        if(num >= 0) { // positive numbers
            char[] arr = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
            reverse(arr);
            return Integer.parseInt(new String(arr));

        } else { // negative numbers
            num *= -1;
            char[] arr = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
            reverse(arr);
            return -Integer.parseInt(new String(arr));
        }
    }

    void reverse(char[] arr) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length - 1;
        while (start < end) {
            char temp = arr[start];
            arr[start++] = arr[end];
            arr[end--] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

---

For one of the test cases, I am getting the following error:

```
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9646324351"
  at line 68, java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString
  at line 658, java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt
  at line 776, java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt
  at line 6, Solution.reverse
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

---

I do not understand why the test case is failing? Any indications to resolve the exception or to improve the solution would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, codereview is for refactoring working code to even better code. [SO] can help you with bugs. Therefor, you should ask your question on codereview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java and many others, `int` is a 32-bit data type which means it has the range $[-2^31, 2^31– 1]$. For the input "1534236569" which is reversed to "9646324351" is outside this range. As stated in the note, consider returning 0 when this occurs.

Comment: Don't answer _off-topic_ questions here please. Code Review is for already working code only.